# php ajax multilevel dependent dropdownlist is not working (yii)

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Hello i tried to create multilevel dependent dropdownlist using yii CHTML dropdownlist. Here is my code :

view _form.php

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'kode_program'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'kode_program',
            $list_prog,array(
            'prompt'=>'--Pilih--',
                'ajax' => array(
                            'type'=>'POST',
                            'url'=>CController::createUrl('OPS/loadKegiatan'),
                            'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'kode_kegiatan'),
                            'data'=>array('kode_program'=>'js:this.value',),                        
            ))

            ); ?>

        <?php echo $form->error($model,'kode_program'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'kode_kegiatan'); ?>
        <?php 
        //echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'kode_kegiatan', $list_keg, array('prompt' => '--Pilih--'));
        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'kode_kegiatan', array(),array(
            'prompt'=>'--Pilih--',
                'ajax' => array(
                            'type'=>'POST',
                            'url'=>CController::createUrl('OPS/loadOutput'),
                            'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'kode_output'),
                            'data'=>array(
                                'kode_kegiatan'=>'js:this.value',
                            ),                      
            )));?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'kode_kegiatan'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'kode_output'); ?>
        <?php
        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'kode_output',array(), array('prompt' => '--Pilih--'));
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'kode_output'); ?>
    </div>
```

controller OPSController.php

```
public function actionLoadKegiatan()
    {
        $data=KodePOK::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('kode_program'=>$_POST['kode_program']));

        $data=CHtml::listData($data,'kode_kegiatan','nama_kegiatan');
        foreach($data as $value=>$name)  {
                echo CHtml::tag('option',
                   array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }

    }

    public function actionLoadOutput()
    {
        $data=KodePOK::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
            //'kode_program'=>$_POST['kode_program'],
            'kode_kegiatan'=>$_POST['kode_kegiatan']
        ));

        $data=CHtml::listData($data,'kode_output','nama_output');
        foreach($data as $value=>$name)  {
                echo CHtml::tag('option',
                   array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
        }

    }
```

The code above doesn't show any error but it isn't working, i dont know why. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. I added :

```
echo CHtml::tag('option',array('value'=>""),"--Pilih--",true);
```

and it works. Here is the full code of the action :

```
public function actionLoadKegiatan()
    {
            $data=KodePOK::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('kode_program'=>$_POST['kode_program']));

            $data=CHtml::listData($data,'kode_kegiatan','nama_kegiatan');
            echo CHtml::tag('option',array('value'=>""),"--Pilih--",true);
            foreach($data as $value=>$name)  {
                    echo CHtml::tag('option',array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
        }

    }
```